# ¿Como realizar un backup a una base de datos en Postgresql desde la terminal?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hola quisiera saber de que manera puedo generar un backup de una base de datos en formato sql en postgresql desde la terminal. Es decir mi deseo es poder sacarle una copia a una base de datos con extensión .sql  que se encuentra bajo el motor de base de dato Postgresql 9.6 por ejemplo que sea algo así backup-14.sql pero hacerlo desde la terminal de linux

Comment: $ pg_dump nombre_bd > archivo.sql

Comment: y si quiero que me genere el archivo sql en una ruta en especifico solamente debería indicarle la ruta cierto?

Comment: pg_dump nombre_bd > /home/usuario/Documentos/archivo.sql  asi por ejemplo

Comment: Ok muchas gracias

Comment: Saludos @IgmerRodriguez podrias agregar tu comentario como respuesta para futuras preguntas en SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como usuario normal (`$`) puedes ejecutar el siguiente comando en una terminal:

```
 pg_dump nombre_bd > ruta/archivo.sql
```

Primero especificas el nombre de la base de datos y luego le dices la ruta donde se guardará.

ejemplo:

```
pg_dump bd_cobros > /home/igmer/Documentos/backup1403190838.sql
```

Nota: al nombre del del `backup` le puedes agregar la fecha y hora de realización para poder distinguirlos.